# Funcion para eliminar registros de una tabla con un condicion. (HTML,Bootstrap, jquery, php, mysql)

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, bootstrap

Bien. Tengo una BD. Ahora estoy trabajando con dos tablas. Una es Clientes la otra ClientesCobrar.
La idea es la siguiente; Tengo un Formulario de Agregar Clientes A Cobrar y por otro formulario de Clientes A Cobrar.
En el primer formulario Un user carga los Clientes A Cobrar para que el user 2 desde el otro Formulario Vea los CLientes A cobrar y los pueda ir contactando para gestionar los cobros.. Los formularios ya los tengo hechos.

Ahora mi idea es Cuando el cliente ha sido cobrado. Que se elimine de la lista de clientes a cobrar
Bien. Tengo una BD. Ahora estoy trabajando con dos tablas. Una es Clientes la otra ClientesCobrar.
La idea es la siguiente; Tengo un Formulario de Agregar Clientes A Cobrar y por otro formulario de Clientes A Cobrar.
En el primer formulario Un user carga los Clientes A Cobrar para que el user 2 desde el otro Formulario Vea los CLientes A cobrar y los pueda ir contactando para gestionar los cobros.. Los formularios ya los tengo hechos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora mi idea es Cuando el cliente ha sido cobrado. Que se elimine de la lista de clientes a cobrar

el codigo para agregar cobranzas es

```
 <?php
    require_once ('../../../../php/conexion.php');
    $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    $contacto = $_POST['contacto'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $cobrado = $_POST['cobrado'];
    $fechaEstimada = $_POST['fechaEstimada'];
    $metodoPago = $_POST['metodoPago'];
    $recepcion = $_POST['recepcion'];
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
    
    $sql="insert into cobranzas (codigo, cliente, contacto, fecha, cobrado, fechaEstimada, metodoPago, recepcion, comentario)
        VALUES ('".$codigo."','".$cliente."','".$contacto."','".$fecha."','".$cobrado."','".$fechaEstimada."','".$metodoPago."','".$recepcion."','".$comentario."')";
            $ret=$mysqli->query($sql);
            $res = "<h3 style='color: red;'>Registro No Enviado.</h3>";
            if ($ret == 1){
                $res = "<h3 style='color: green;'>¡Registro Agregado Correctamente!</h3>";
            }
            
            $mysqli->close();
            echo ($res);
            ?>
```

Comment: Me parece que la logica no es correcta. Si vas a eliminar el cliente al que le has cobrado, cual es el sentido de llenar todos los campos?  Creo que sea que le cobres o no, deberias guardar los datos y tener una columna que guarde el dato si le has cobrado o no. Luego puedes filtrar con ese campo para los demas propositos (para ver quien no se ha cobrado por ejemplo).

Comment: asi es, explique mal. Tengo dos tablas, las de Cobranzas y otra de clientesCobrar. La que quiero que se eliminen los registros es la de clientesCobrar, asi lo que le toca al user1 es solo agregar los que necesitan ser contactados por User2.